# React / Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to pass an Object from one Class to another which are in separate files. The overall goal is to consolidate my API calls into a single .js file for reference throughout the app.

The issue I'm having here is I'm unable to access the variables within the object within the .js file that calls the class.

**Scenario:**
I make my API calls in *APICall.js* and then attempt to pass the response data back to *Page.js*. I'm able to see my object in *Page.js*; however, I can't seem to access any of the variables to update my state.

Note: I'm new to ReactJS (and Javascript) with a solid Python background. Obviously these are two completely different beasts here.

Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide!

**Console Logs Issues**

1. :20 Object appears empty but shows values when extending.
2. :21 is a blank line but should be logging the first_name
3. :30 is a blank Object all together

--

```
TESTING !@#
UpperNavigation.js:20 {first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "", company: ""}
    company: "Testing 123"
    email: "john@somewebsite.com"
    first_name: "John"
    last_name: "Doe"
    __proto__: Object

UpperNavigation.js:21 

UpperNavigation.js:30 {first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "", company: ""}
    company: ""
    email: ""
    first_name: ""
    last_name: ""
    __proto__: Object
```

*Page.js*

```
state = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    company: ''
}

componentWillMount() {
    // this.getUserProfile.bind(this)
    var userData = new vAPI().getUserProfile()
    console.log("TESTING !@#");
    console.log(userData)
    console.log(userData.first_name);

    this.setState({
        first_name: userData.first_name,
        last_name: userData.last_name,
        email: userData.email,
        company: userData.company
    });

    console.log(this.state);
}
```

*APICall.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class vAPI {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            first_name: "",
            last_name: "",
            email: "",
            company: ""
        }
    }

    getUserProfile(){
        const URL = "https://somewebsite.com/api/user_profile/"
        const USER_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        const AuthStr = 'JWT '.concat(USER_TOKEN);

        axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(response => {
            this.state.first_name = response.data.first_name
            this.state.last_name = response.data.last_name
            this.state.email = response.data.email
            this.state.company = response.data.company            

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('error 3 ' + error);
            });

        return (this.state);
    };
}
```

Comment: 1. In React, you're supposed to mutate state using `this.setState()` 2. `axios.get()` is asynchronous; when you call `return (this.state);` the API call isn't finished yet. The solution is most likely to 1. return the entire `axios` call instead 2. in `Page.js`, call `.then()` on it and inside, call `this.setState()`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, got me going int the right direction. I have RyanC the answer for completeness, but you got me heading in the direction he took it. Thanks!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to use a class and have a state in your APICall.js; you can simply `export default { getUserProfile: () => { ... }};` and call `vAPI.getUserProfile()` to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getUserProfile()` you are returning `this.state` before your axios get request is complete. When you call `getUserProfile()` from Page.js you are  trying to access the data before it is set from your get request.

---

You should be returning the promise in `getUserProfile()` then using [async/await](https://gist.github.com/wesbos/1866f918824936ffb73d8fd0b02879b4) or `.then()` when you call it in `componentWillMount()` before setting the data

```
getUserProfile(){
  const URL = "https://somewebsite.com/api/user_profile/"
  const USER_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  const AuthStr = 'JWT '.concat(USER_TOKEN);

  return axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
};
```

**async/await**

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const userDataRes = await (new vAPI().getUserProfile());
  const userData = userDataRes.data;

  this.setState({
    first_name: userData.first_name,
    last_name: userData.last_name,
    email: userData.email,
    company: userData.company,
  });

  console.log('state', this.state);
}
```

**promise**

```
componentWillMount() {
  new vAPI().getUserProfile().then((userDataRes) => {
    const userData = userDataRes.data;

    this.setState({
      first_name: userData.first_name,
      last_name: userData.last_name,
      email: userData.email,
      company: userData.company,
    });

    console.log('state', this.state);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RyanC! I ended up going with this concept: https://codeburst.io/how-to-call-api-in-a-smart-way-2ca572c6fe86

Question, which is the preferred method, promise or await?

Comment: I personally definitely prefer async/await, it makes the code much cleaner especially when doing a bunch of asynchronous calls